# How to get informations through a @JoinTable with HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have 2 entities : `task` and `user`. One task can have several users. So I use `@jointable` annotation like below :

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "tasks_users",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "taskid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

However, when I try to get all task with a `GET` request, I have only tasks informations, not informations about users :

*Get all tasks*

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "task": [
            {
                "taskname": "Football",
                "taskchief": "Jean Dupond",
                "startdate": "2019-02-18",
                "enddate": "2019-05-05",
                "status": 1,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8082/tasks/de7d9052-4961-4b4f-938a-3cd12cbe1f82"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "taskname": "Blockchain project",
                "taskchief": "Léo Dubois",
                "startdate": "2019-03-01",
                "enddate": "2019-06-24",
                "status": 1,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8082/tasks/425e7701-02c6-4de3-9333-a2459eece1c8"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/tasks"
        }
    }
}
```

Is that normal behavior?

Thanks for your answers and advises.

PS : Tell me if you need specific code, I will upload it.

Comment: The code seems to be good. Did you missing the getter setter for users maybe ?

Comment: @Pred05 nop it work when I'm not using links HATEOAS. But if I use links, users disapears...

Comment: While it might always sound good from a processing standpoint to send data in batch and therefore reduce the number of requests in order to fulfill a task, the drawback to this approach is, that you simply can't make use of caching effectively. Especially user data shouldn't change that often and would therefore be highly suited for caching, which may reduce load on the server even more than by forcefully attemping to reduce the number of request by sending out everything in one batch. Caching is thus one of the few constraints of REST and not an option

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the fetch type for loading your entities USERS. 
By default, in a many-to-many relationship between two entities, JPA applies LAZY loading.
This means that your entities will be loaded only on demand and in particular at the first call of the accessor method.
If you change your fetch type as EAGER, then by default, the USER(S) associated with the TASKS entities, in your case, will be loaded into your collections of USERS.

You can achieve that by doing as follow :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "tasks_users",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "taskid") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userid") })
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```